# receiving ID of Pending Intent from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I need to access the `ID` of the Pending Intent from the `Broadcast Receiver` class. 
Here is the code of my Main Activity from which I set the Alarm using PendingIntent.

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{


    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); //where pen is the ID
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

And here is the code of my Broadcast Receiver:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        int vibrator = intent.getIntExtra("vibrator", 1);

        //PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);



        //intent to call the activity which shows on ringing
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Time_Date.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);

        //display that alarm is ringing
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Ringing...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);




    }


}
```

Can I use `Intent.putExtra()` to receive the same or any other easy way to get the unique ID to the Broadcast Receiver? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, just use an Extra in the Intent, and get the Extra in the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks, but my doubt was, as the id is binded along with the Pending intent, is it possible to access the Id from Broadcast receiver w/o using intent.extra method ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, as you only have access to the Intent in the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks, but one more doubt.  As you can see from my code, I am launching another activity from this Broadcast Receiver, So do I need to pass the value again from the Broadcast receiver to the launching activity to receive the value there  ? Or can I get that value from main Activity to this launching activity directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second argument to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is meant to be used by the component that eventually receives the intent (at least I have found no way to access it). If you want to pass some data along that is specific to your app, just use an extra.